# Column was specified multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have joined two tables and I want to use `GROUP BY` but I am getting error.
I have tried replacing all the columns instead of * but it is not working.

```
SELECT t.*

       FROM
(select O.[CUSTADDRESSID]
      ,O.[ACCOUNTNO]
      ,O.[ADDRESSTYPE]
      ,O.[ADDRESSLINE1]
      ,O.[ISCOMMUNICATION]
      ,C.[CUSTOMERID]
      ,C.[ACCOUNTNO]
      ,C.[ACCOUNTGROUPID]
      ,C.[PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID]
      ,C.[PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE]

from [ISSUER].[HISTORY].[TP_CUSTOMER_PREPAIDACCOUNTS] c
full join  [ISSUER].[PLAY].[TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES] o
on c.ACCOUNTNO = o.ACCOUNTNO)  as t
group by ACCOUNTNO
```

I want to remove the duplicate `ACCOUNTNO` from the Join result.

Comment: I think you can find some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672058/sql-the-column-xxx-was-specified-multiple-times-for-yyy)

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you used t.* that means you selected all the column but used only one column in group by thats why you got that error, now if you just use accountno in selection and use having cluse for filter duplicate account no then you can use `count` aggregate function and below query

```
SELECT [ACCOUNTNO]
           FROM
          (select O.[CUSTADDRESSID]
          ,O.[ACCOUNTNO]
          ,O.[ADDRESSTYPE]
          ,O.[ADDRESSLINE1]
          ,O.[ISCOMMUNICATION]
          ,C.[CUSTOMERID]
          ,C.[ACCOUNTNO] as C_ACCOUNTNO
          ,C.[ACCOUNTGROUPID]
          ,C.[PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID]
          ,C.[PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE]

    from [ISSUER].[HISTORY].[TP_CUSTOMER_PREPAIDACCOUNTS] c
    full join  [ISSUER].[PLAY].[TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES] o
    on c.ACCOUNTNO = o.ACCOUNTNO
   )  as t
    group by ACCOUNTNO
    having count([ACCOUNTNO])>1
```

But if you want your query then you have to use `distinct`

```
SELECT distinct t.*

       FROM
(select O.[CUSTADDRESSID]
      ,O.[ACCOUNTNO]
      ,O.[ADDRESSTYPE]
      ,O.[ADDRESSLINE1]
      ,O.[ISCOMMUNICATION]
      ,C.[CUSTOMERID]
      ,C.[ACCOUNTNO] as C_ACCOUNTNO
      ,C.[ACCOUNTGROUPID]
      ,C.[PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID]
      ,C.[PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE]

from [ISSUER].[HISTORY].[TP_CUSTOMER_PREPAIDACCOUNTS] c
full join  [ISSUER].[PLAY].[TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES] o
on c.ACCOUNTNO = o.ACCOUNTNO)  as t
```

You can learn about [group by](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/04/do-you-really-understand-sqls-group-by-and-having-clauses/)

Comment: this query really works ? the `ACCOUNTNO` still appearing twice in the inner query

Comment: @Squirrel thanks i have not got 2nd account no i changed that one

Answer (score 3):

you have specified the same `ACCOUNTNO` twice in your inner query

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
select O.[CUSTADDRESSID]
      ,O.[ACCOUNTNO]             -- 1st occurance
      ,O.[ADDRESSTYPE]
      ,O.[ADDRESSLINE1]
      ,O.[ISCOMMUNICATION]
      ,C.[CUSTOMERID]
      ,C.[ACCOUNTNO]             -- second occurance
      ,C.[ACCOUNTGROUPID]
      ,C.[PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID]
      ,C.[PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE]    
from [ISSUER].[HISTORY].[TP_CUSTOMER_PREPAIDACCOUNTS] c
full join  [ISSUER].[PLAY].[TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES] o
on c.ACCOUNTNO = o.ACCOUNTNO)  as t
--group by ACCOUNTNO
```

You can use alias one one of the `ACCOUNTNO` , example

```
,O.[ACCOUNTNO] AS ACCNO1
,C.[ACCOUNTNO] AS ACCNO2
```

OR alternatively

since you are doing a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on ACCOUNTNO
you should use `COALESCE()` to return either from `TP_CUSTOMER_PREPAIDACCOUNTS` or `TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES`

change your inner query to

```
select  O.[CUSTADDRESSID]
       ,COALESCE(O.[ACCOUNTNO], C.[ACCOUNTNO]) AS ACCOUNTNO
       ,O.[ADDRESSTYPE]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query: it will give u duplicate accountno

```
SELECT [ACCOUNTNO],count([ACCOUNTNO])
          FROM
    (select O.[CUSTADDRESSID]
          ,O.[ACCOUNTNO]
          ,O.[ADDRESSTYPE]
          ,O.[ADDRESSLINE1]
          ,O.[ISCOMMUNICATION]
          ,C.[CUSTOMERID]
          ,C.[ACCOUNTNO] as accountno_c
          ,C.[ACCOUNTGROUPID]
          ,C.[PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID]
          ,C.[PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE]

    from [ISSUER].[HISTORY].[TP_CUSTOMER_PREPAIDACCOUNTS] c
    full join  [ISSUER].[PLAY].[TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES] o
    on c.ACCOUNTNO = o.ACCOUNTNO)  as t
    group by ACCOUNTNO
    having count([ACCOUNTNO])>1
```